# DIV truncated with ellipsis in short form, expanded on clicking icon

Tags: css

In this fiddle I need to truncate a DIV to an initial width of 250px, which I am doing already with '...'; on clicking my own '?' button it then expands to 500px:

https://jsfiddle.net/my8jpn01/16/

CSS

```
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  /* need automatic multi-line height */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border:1px solid #999999;
  float: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

JS

```
$('.helpicon').on('click', function () {
$('.truncate').css('width','500px');
$('.truncate').css('overflow','visible');
});
```

My problems:

1. The expanded DIV must be multi-line, variable height. Right now it overflows, even with the word-wrap. Setting a height doesn't work.
2. Is there a way to make the '?' part of the truncated DIV?
3. There should be a 'Hide' link once expanded to revert to the original compressed version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very quick example. You can do it by adding/removing a class. Set class specific style for the properties you need.

```
.truncate.truncated {
    white-space: initial;
    width: 500px;
}
```

DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/my8jpn01/19/

IE11 does not like `initial` for `white-space`. Use `inherit` if applicable or `normal` to revert to default.

```
.truncate.truncated {
    white-space: normal;
    width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: @geneb. Intial has unexpected behaviour in IE11 it would appear. Use inherit or normal. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

Instead of changing the CSS properties of the div with jquery, instead you can use jquery to add (toggle) a class to the div and set multiple properties at once.

```js
$(function () {

 $('.helpicon').on('click', function () {
  //get the current text value of the ? or X
  var text = $('.helpicon').text();
        //when we click the ? or X, toggle an open class
   $('.truncate').toggleClass('open');
    //toggle the X with an ?
    $('.helpicon').text(text == "X" ? "?":"X");
 });
  
});
```

```css
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  /* need automatic multi-line height */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border:1px solid #999999;
  float: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.truncate.open {
  width: 500px;
  white-space: normal;
  text-overflow: inherit;
}

.helpicon {
  position: relative;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="truncate">
 <a class="helpicon" href="#">
    ?
 </a>
  Explanation text provided in this truncated paragraph which can be expanded by clicking the 'i' Information icon -- now you are viewing the full paragraph in expanded form -- multiline example
</div>
```